# Serializing and deserializing an object that doesn't implement Serializable

Tags: java, serialization, jboss, deserialization

### Motivation:

To aid in remote debugging (Java), it's useful to be able to request remote servers to send over arbitrary objects to my local machine for inspection. However, this means that the remote server must be able to serialize an arbitrary java object that is not known in advance at runtime.

In particular, I would like to be able to serialize even those objects which **don't implement `Serializable`**. I stumbled upon [JBossSerialization](http://serialization.jboss.org/) which claimed with that with JBossSerialization...

> ...You can serialize classes that are not implementing Serializable

Great! And even better, I managed to find [the code that supposedly demonstrates how to do this](http://www.schabell.org/2009/03/jboss-serialization-simple-example.html).

### Problem

So pinching [the code from schabell.org](http://www.schabell.org/2009/03/jboss-serialization-simple-example.html), I wrote a quick test to check that I could serialize and deserialize without problems:

```
import org.jboss.serial.io.JBossObjectInputStream;
import org.jboss.serial.io.JBossObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.*;

class MyObj {   // Test class which doesn't implement Serializable
    public int x;
    MyObj(int x) {this.x = x;}
}

public class SerializationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObj obj = new MyObj(1);
        byte[] byteArray = getByteArrayFromObject(obj);            // Try to serialize
        MyObj result = (MyObj) getObjectFromByteArray(byteArray);  // Try to deserialize
        System.out.println(result.x);
    }

    // Code that I pinched from website below (http://www.schabell.org/2009/03/jboss-serialization-simple-example.html):
    public static Object getObjectFromByteArray(byte[] bytes) {
        Object result = null;

        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new JBossObjectInputStream(bais);
            result = ois.readObject();   // ERROR HERE!!!
            ois.close();
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfEx) {
            cnfEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] getByteArrayFromObject(Object obj) {
        byte[] result = null;

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new JBossObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            baos.close();
            result = baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Problem is that the test failed. Debugging indicated that I could only serialize, but not deserialize. The call to `ois.readObject()` on line 26 is the culprit and gives as `SerializationException`:

```
org.jboss.serial.exception.SerializationException: Could not create instance of MyObj - MyObj
    at org.jboss.serial.classmetamodel.ClassMetaData.newInstance(ClassMetaData.java:342)
    at org.jboss.serial.persister.RegularObjectPersister.readData(RegularObjectPersister.java:239)
    at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.readObjectDescriptionFromStreaming(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:412)
    at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.ObjectDescriptorFactory.objectFromDescription(ObjectDescriptorFactory.java:82)
    at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerDirectInput.readObject(DataContainer.java:643)
    at org.jboss.serial.io.JBossObjectInputStream.readObjectOverride(JBossObjectInputStream.java:163)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364)
    at SerializationTest.getObjectFromByteArray(SerializationTest.java:44)
    at SerializationTest.main(SerializationTest.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: MyObj
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:359)
    at org.jboss.serial.classmetamodel.ClassMetaData.newInstance(ClassMetaData.java:334)
    ... 8 more
```

Does anyone know what's going wrong here and how I can get round this?

Or indeed if JBossSerialization isn't the right tool for this, what is?

### Edit:

As @Dima points out, the `SerializationException` is caused by a lack of a public default constructor of the `MyObj` class. However, adding a default constructor to `MyObj` isn't an option as I'd like to be able to serialize **arbitrary** objects, including those without a default constructor.

Comment: This looks like regular old serialization.  You might try [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) it's worked for me before.

Comment: Why `Serializable`? Why not use a protocol for this which is more robust|easier to use like, for instance, JSON?

Comment: @fge because I've only ever used `Serializable` before so I just started from there. So JSON serialization doesn't require an object to be `Serializable`?

Comment: No it doesn't. Nor do any Protobuf libraries, for that matter. JSON is a pretty well established standard, so if you choose it, you can't lose. Try and have a look at Jackson for instance.

Comment: Another option would be xml using jaxb (or something similar). Either xml or json would be far more portable and interoperable than class serialization.

Comment: to be clear, binary serialization is not very portable.  java serialization is pluggable, and the default implementation supports xml export/import if portability is a concern.  additionally, you can plug your own serialization handlers if you need custom serialization as well.

Comment: You truncated the traceback (interesting part starts after the next "Caused By"), so, there isn't very much I can help with here other than offer a guess, that it, probably, wants your object to have a default constructor (or a public one?).

Comment: As to choosing serialization approach, the main problem with java default serialization is its performance (that does not exist). If jboss' claim to be 10 times faster is true, then I think it might be a very good choice. Forget json and xml, they are both bulky and slow. Protobufs, thrift or kryo may be a better choice, but they are real pain in the neck to implement and maintain. Their main feature is interoperability between different languages. So, if you only care about java, and jboss works for you, it might very well be the way to go.

Comment: @Dima - you are right, the `SerializationException` is caused by a lack of a public default constructor of the `MyObj` class. Adding a default constructor to `MyObj` isn't an option as I'd like to be able to serialize **arbitrary** objects, including those without a default constructor. Any ideas as to workarounds? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is actually *impossible* to do what you want in a way, that would be both safe and universal.

You can take a look at [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#quickstart), as someone suggested in comments as well. It does have a way to instantiate objects without invoking a constructor, but it is off by default and *there is a good reason for it*.

Consider this for example:

```
public class CanonicalObject {
    public static HashMap<String,CannicalObject> canons = new HahMap<~>();
    public String name;
    private CanonicalObject(String name) { 
        this.name = name;            
        canons.put(name, this);
    }
    public static synchronized CanonicalObject getCanonicalInstance(String name) {            
        CanonicalObject co = canon.get(name);
        return co == null ? new CanonicalObject(name) : co;
    }
}
```

(This is a "semi-real-life" example, in that there are real uses for this pattern. I am aware of the "memory leak", there are ways to avoid it in real applications, but they are irrelevant to this example, so I am just ignoring that issue for the sake of simplicity).

If you serialize an instance of this object, when you deserialize it on the other end, the whole "canonicalization" part will be skipped, which can cause subtle problems in application, that are *really* hard to diagnose, such as comparisons like `if(canon1 != canon2) fireMissile()` resulting in "friendly fire" and, possibly, a WorldWar III.

Note, that the problem here is broader than just a constructor not invoked by deserialization: the `canon.put` call could very well be put into `getCanonicalInstance()` instead of the constructor, and that would present the problem even if the constructor was invoked.

This is an illustration of why, as a matter of policy, you should not be serializing objects that are not designed to be serialized. IT can sometimes work, but, when it does not, it results in situations that are really hard to detect, and usually even harder to fix.

Comment: Thanks, but in your above example, surely the `static` `canons` field gets serialized and deserialized along with the object, no? Thus it is well and good that the constructor and 'canonicalization' is skipped because the deserialized `canons` field would therefore already contain a reference to the object.

Comment: Taking your advice in trying Kryo, I am now getting an `IllegalAccessError`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731969/serializing-an-arbitrary-java-object-with-kryo-getting-illegalaccesserror