# Serializing an arbitrary Java object with Kryo (getting IllegalAccessError)

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, kryo

### Motivation:

To aid in remote debugging (Java), it's useful to be able to request remote servers to send over arbitrary objects to my local machine for inspection. However, this means that the remote server must be able to serialize an arbitrary java object that is not known in advance at runtime.

So I asked around and stumbled on the [Kryo serialization library](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo). From [Kryo's documentation](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#quickstart), a major feature is that it's very robust at serializing arbitrary java objects. Objects don't have to implement `Serializable`, don't need no-arg constructors to be deserializable and I don't even need to know anything about the structure of the object prior to serialization. Perfect!

### Problem:

So to test Kryo out, I tried to see if I could serialize and then deserialize a `PrintWriter` object (i.e. an arbitrary object):

```
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Input;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output;
import java.io.*;

public class SerializationTest {

    private static final String ioFileName = "someIO.bin";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a PrintWriter object that I will later attempt to serialize
        PrintWriter outObj = null;
        try {
            outObj = new PrintWriter("textfile.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Change the PrintWriter's state as a test for later to see if state is restored after serialization and deserialization
        outObj.println("Hello");   // "Hello" held in PrintWriter's buffer

        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();    // Initialize Kryo serialization
        writeObj(kryo, outObj);    // Save PrintWriter object to file with "Hello" still in its buffer

        // Read the previously saved Printwriter object (still with "Hello" in its buffer)
        PrintWriter inObj = (PrintWriter) readObj(kryo);

        inObj.close();    // commit "Hello" to disk (using deserialized object)
        outObj.close();   // commit "Hello" to disk (using original object)

        System.out.println(inObj);
    }

    public static Object readObj(Kryo kryo) {
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            Input input = new Input(new FileInputStream(ioFileName));
            obj = kryo.readClassAndObject(input);   // ERROR HERE!!
            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public static void writeObj(Kryo kryo, Object obj) {
        try {
            Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream(ioFileName));
            kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, obj);
            output.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Serialization works fine, but upon deserialization the call to `kryo.readClassAndObject(input)` on line 39 gives the following `IllegalAccessError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class sun.nio.cs.UTF_8 from class sun.nio.cs.UTF_8ConstructorAccess
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8ConstructorAccess.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo$DefaultInstantiatorStrategy$1.newInstance(Kryo.java:1234)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1086)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.create(FieldSerializer.java:547)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:523)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:704)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:704)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:704)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:704)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:106)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:528)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:786)
    at SerializationTest.readObj(SerializationTest.java:39)
    at SerializationTest.main(SerializationTest.java:27)
```

I had hoped that I could serialize and deserialize the `PrintWriter` object `outObj`, and the object's state would remain in tact so I could still use the deserialized object to write `"Hello"` which would have been held in buffer.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to rectify this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you want `kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy());` to avoid constructor invocation. 
More info [here](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo#object-creation).

But, if I may ask, why in the world would you want to serialize a `PrintWriter`? That is definitely asking for trouble. 
Kryo is not a "silver bullet", while its default derializers can work with *most* classes, that are practical (and even then there are always corner cases for which you need to write custom plugins), you can certainly not expect it to be able to handle every single exotic thing you can come up with (and serializing classes backed by internal jvm-specific code, like `sun.*` definitely qualifies as exotic).

Comment: Thanks @Dima - perhaps I should explain that my aim with all of this is that I run a lot of code on remote servers. Therefore, from the perspective of remote debugging, it would be very useful for me to be able to pick *any object* on the server at will and send it to my local machine for inspection. In this respect, I was indeed hoping to be able to serialize arbitrary and possibly 'exotic' objects. I chose to serialize a `PrintWriter` in my example simply because it was the first 'exotic' object that came to mind. So are you saying that this kind of live remote debugging is not possible?

Comment: Why not just use a debugger? ;) Or JMX? Or a beanshell? It does look like you are reinventing a bicycle. It is not impossible, but is, probably, way more complicated than you are envisioning. And I'll ask again ... why in the world would you want to "debug" a `PrintWriter`?

Comment: I have tried Beanshell, but the only problem is that it is restricted to a telnet interface and returns server objects in a printed string-form only. This is OK if there is a human doing the debugging and interacting with the remote Beanshell instance via a telnet client. However, I have written procedures locally that produce analysis on arbitrary objects. I want to return server objects as objects, with complete structure in tact, so that I may analyse them in my local code. Can JMX do this? As for `PrintWriter`, it was just a random choice to see if Kryo could handle 'exotic' objects.

Answer (score 0):

This error is pretty common with Kryo. Problem is that UTF_8 class is not public and hence Kryo fails.  Adding below custom serializer helped me to resolve it. It would be a good idea to ship below kind of serializer along with Kryo as lot of people struggles with this.

[Custom serializer for kryo for UTF-8 and other charsets](https://github.com/jagrutmehta/kryo-UTF/blob/master/KryoCharsetSeralizer.java)

This way you are telling Kryo that for all registered Charset classes, call my custom serializer. Where I am just emitting string name.