# PrintWriter mystery in Ignite

Tags: ignite

I am using two nodes, one that starts off the computation from the IDE (Intellij IDEA) and another that has already been started on the console (remote debugging enabled). I am debugging both from the IDE.

I am not using peerClassLoading, I have placed the jar in the libs from the console node.

There is a line of code: `System.out.println(x);` - which prints fine in both. But the following lines:

```
getPrintWriter().println(x);
getPrintWriter().flush();
```

work only on the node started from the IDE. The PrintWriter wraps a System.out. The console node throws IOException - 'the file handle is invalid' during flush.

Here is the screenshot of the stacktrace:

[image]

and here is the relevant part of the code with the console node:

[image]

---

Following suggestion, I reset the print writer and the issue was resolved. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

---

**The Serialization Context**

Here is the part of the code that starts up the ignite computation:

[image]

For the node on console JVM, `ConsoleClient` gets serialized and so its containing classes (commands, listeners and their print writers etc.). In the list `clients`, all `ConsoleClient` objects had their print writers as wrappers of `System.out`, so ideally, the marked block in the runnable should not be needed. Note that, if this marked block is removed the IDE nodes print properly, but not the console node.

Comment: Can you show the full trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `PrintWriter` tries to delegate to `FileOutputStream`, so it's either not `System.out` underneath or `System.out` is replaced. Ignite never does this, so the issue is not related to it. You should check the code of `getPrintWriter()` method and make sure that `System.out` is the console writer that you're looking for.

Comment: Resetting the print writer solved the issue (see the screenshot in the question edit). However, I am still not clear how the marshalling process (the listener was originally created on the IDE process, but gets executed on the console JVM) created a non-null but different printwriter. I realize that I should not depend on printwriter serialization as it is system specific (http://stackoverflow.com/q/27731969/225866), but if you could provide some pointers towards the serialization process used in Ignite and how I can dig into it through the debugger, that would be great.

Comment: It looks like this happens within your class, no? Why do you think it's somehow connected to Ignite serialization protocols?

Comment: I have edited the question adding the serialization context.